# Unable to generate access token for microsoft graph online meeting api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have tried everything but somehow unable to generate token or the token that is generated does not work. Please help with what I am doing wrong. I want the token to create an online meeting.
Sharing requests below which I have tried

1. Generate token with client credentials grant type
   REQUEST:

   POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/CXXXXXXX/oauth2/token' 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   --data-urlencode 'password=CXXXXXXX' 
   --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' 
   --data-urlencode 'scope=OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite' 
   --data-urlencode 'client_id=CXXXXXXXCXXXXXXX-464c-965a-CXXXXXXXCXXXXXXX' 
   --data-urlencode 'username=CXXXXXXX@gmail.com' 
   --data-urlencode 'client_secret=CXXXXXXX6ryCXXXXXXXuV.zu8SmW~D_'

Save the token generated- Using this in https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings gives error - Access token validation failure. Invalid audience

2. Use this token as assertion as follows

   POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/learn123456789.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token'
   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   --data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'
   --data-urlencode 'scope=OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite' 
   --data-urlencode 'client_id=CXXXXXXXCXXXXXXX-464c-965a-CXXXXXXXCXXXXXXX' 
   --data-urlencode 'client_secret=CXXXXXXX6ryCXXXXXXXuV.zu8SmW~D_' 
   --data-urlencode 'resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/' 
   --data-urlencode 'requested_token_use=on_behalf_of' 
   --data-urlencode 'assertion=tokenFromFirstAPI'
3. Also tried this api

   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CXXXXXXXCXXXXXXX-464c-965a-CXXXXXXXCXXXXXXX&response_type=token&resource=XXXXXXX6-ba00-4fd7-XXXXXXXXX3

Error is
Assertion audience does not match the Client app presenting the assertion. The audience in the assertion was '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' and the expected audience is 'clientID' or one of the Application Uris of this application with App ID XXX. The downstream client must request a token for the expected audience (the application that made the OBO request) and this application should use that token as the assertion.

No token works in this - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings

Getting - "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please check the permissions once and try using the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Answer (score 0):

As your error message says, your token audience is invalid , because you set the wrong `scope` when requesting the token. You should set the scope to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`, in addition, the api call only supports `delegated permissions`, so you can't use the client credential flow to get the token. For the `/me` endpoint, the user needs to log in, so you need Use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token.

[image]

Or, there is a simpler method, you can use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test, you only need to log in to the user and add permissions.

[image]

---

**Update:**

I noticed that you use 3 methods to get the token.

First of all, for the first method, you are using a v1.0 endpoint and use the client credential flow to obtain the token. What you need to pay attention to is that when you use v1.0 authentication, you cannot use `scope`, you should use `resource`. In addition, when you use the client credential flow, you cannot use the v1.0 version , you need to use the beta version, and because the client credential flow is a flow without user login, you cannot call the `/me` endpoint, you should call the `/users` endpoint. (**Note:** When you use the beta version and use the client credential flow, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions): **Administrators must create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) and grant it to a user, authorizing the app configured in the policy to create an online meeting on behalf of that user (user ID specified in the request path).)**

The complete request is:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-xxxxxxxxxx
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuLxxxxxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

api call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings
```

For the second method, I noticed that you are using [OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), and then you pass in the wrong access token obtained by the first method as an assertion, so the access token you obtained using this flow is definitely not correct. . In addition, if you don't have a back-end API, please do not use this flow. This flow requires you to have a middle-tier API, and it is cumbersome to use.

Your third method is also wrong, your resource should be: `https://graph.microsoft.com`

To summarize: If you want to use the client credential flow without user login, please refer to my update. If you don't have a backend api, please do not use OBO flow.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carl bit it did not work

Have even given all the permissions as suggested above.

ERROR- Bad Request - 400 - 819ms

{ "error": { "code": "AuthenticationError", "message": "Error authenticating with resource", "innerError": { "date": "2020-12-27T09:36:57", "request-id": "4e01eff1-9eb5-42dd-9009-dbdd85aca49a", "client-request-id": "5effa441-d7f6-5ef7-5066-1d7153f39712" } }

Comment: Can you use Graph Explorer to test?  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Answer (score 0):

[IMAGE of ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrk7b.png)
Error in following URL

```
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
```

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Did you log in with a work or school account? It does not support Microsoft personal accounts.

Comment: I created personal account as of now. Let me try by creating  work or school account.